# Can the social commentary in "Fear and Loathing in Las Vegas" be applied to the present?

Tags: setting, fear-and-loathing-in-las-vegas, hunter-s-thompson

Recently, I have picked up "Fear and Loathing in Las Vegas" after reading glowing reviews of the book.

However, as I read the book further, I felt that I have completely misunderstood the points it was trying to make - rather, I did not understand them at all. After some research, I have found the most common explanation: the book is a kind of commentary on the society in the US at the time.

This argument does not seem to be particularly fulfilling. After all, if all it was is a commentary on the 1970s, why the appraisal that the book still receives? The fact that it was adapted to a movie almost 30 years later tells me the same.

Perhaps I am missing a crucial point of the book, which didn't seem to contain any plot. That alone is not a big problem, as there are many books without a clear narrative, but combined with the style of writing it made reading this book a challenge.

What is it that makes this book so appealing even now? Can the commentary in it be applied to today's society and if yes, in what way?